# Tagging with jts-topology-suite and/or jsts?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have tags for:

- [jsts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jsts) with 5 questions and a tag wiki excerpt that advises to:

> Use this tag when referring to the jsts (java) library

- [jts-topology-suite](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jts-topology-suite) with 84 questions and a tag wiki excerpt which advises that:

> JTS Topology Suite is an open source Java software library that
>   provides an object model for geometries and functions to work with
>   them.

There are [2 questions tagged with both](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jts-topology-suite+jsts).

Are both tags needed or should they be merged?

Answer (score 3):

I had always assumed that JSTS was for the [Javascript JTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts), so I would consider fixing the wiki instead of merging.

Comment: All five questions tagged [tag:jsts] are about Javascript JTS. +1

Answer (score 1):

Clearly these refer to the same thing. I vote for merging them.

Comment: I noticed some questions tagged [tag:jts-topology-suite] are within the scope of [tag:jsts] as answered by Ian Turton, but it seems just some (not all). Then, I am not sure if they are the same thing, unless java and javascript software/library would be considered in the same scope. In this case, I'd suggest clarifying this POV in the answer.